# How to display the group of dynamic buttons (columns as buttons) using mat-table in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have a requirement with dynamic buttons needs to display in a page using angular8.

And based on drop-down selection buttons will dynamically change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the button in the  ng-container matColumnDef, 
for example

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ACTIONS </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let object">
           <button *ngif="object.condition" (click)="openDrop()"> Trigger drop</button>
           <button>Other botton</button>
         </td>
      </ng-container>
```